# Kubernetes: How do I get a robust status of a pod using python?

Tags: python, kubernetes

I use something like this to get the status of pods.

```
from kubernetes import client
v1core = client.CoreV1Api()

api_response =v1core.list_namespaced_pod(...)
for pod in api_response.items:
    status = pod.status.phase
```

I have some extra code to find out that it is actually an error executing an init container for example. But it feels fragile, I don't know everything that could fail.
It is very complicated to summarize the status of containers, init containers and so on, as good as kubectl and its status column.

```
$kubectl get pods
NAME                                                    READY   STATUS       RESTARTS   AGE
postgres                                                1/1     Running      0          23m
users                                                   1/1     Init:Error   0          23m
```

Are there any way to get the text that is shown in the status column via the API? Or any other robust way to get a good pod status summary.

Comment: I think this is part of the code for the `kubectl` generating this result. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/master/pkg/cmd/get/get.go#L458